# Limit $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}(e^x-1)$ in $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find the limit of  $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x}(e^x-1)$ in $(0,0)$. Note that $x>0,y>0$.

Im sure that it converges to zero, but I haven't find a way yet to show it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

The limit you have
$$L = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\underbrace{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}_{(1)}\underbrace{y}_{(2)}$$
consists of two factors $(1)$ and $(2)$. Note that the expression $(1)$ has the limit of value $1$ and hence bounded. Therefore since $y\to 0$, you have $L = 0$

Comment: omg thanks, I should've seen this! :)